# Ghostcript destination name with blank space returns error

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, ghostscript

I am creating a paint-like app in Python and I am saving the canvas using Ghostscript with subprocess inside python. The script works fine and I get the desired output, but If there is any blank space in the destination, Ghostscript breaks at that point and returns an error.
eg :

```
destination = "/Volumes/Personal/Personal Works/myImage"
convertCode = "gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -r300 -g1000x1000 -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=" + destination + ".png " + tempFile
subprocess.call(convertCode, shell=True)
```

This returns an

> Error: /undefinedfilename in (Works/Untitled.png)

this clearly shows the Ghostscript breaks due to the space in the destination name. Destination with no space in the middle has no problem. How to solve this problem.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh it works :D it's called short name it seems. A quick way to find the pattern for the respective os will be to drag and drop the folder in terminal. Thank you for the fast response :)

Comment: Just put quotes "" around the path and filename. I've no idea how to escape a " in Python but it allows you to use the real path without having to hash it.